# Linq or lambda select all fields modifying one

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is any way to select all fields in a query but modifying one field like this?

```
    var notes = from n in myContext.Notes
                select new 
                {
                  ...   // all fiedls
                  date = n.date.ToString("MM/YYYY") // but one field edited
                }
```

this is the query I want but less verbose when I have several properties.

```
var note = await _dbContext.ClientChartNotes
                  .Select(s => new
                  {
                    s.ClientChartNoteId,
                    s.ClientId,
                    s.ChartNoteType,
                    s.Title,
                    s.Note,
                    ChartNoteDate = s.ChartNoteDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                  })
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ClientChartNoteId.Equals(id));
```

Lambda preferred.

Thanks

Edit: to include original query.

Comment: So you just want to format the value of each property named date in your list?

Comment: Is your intention to have an anonymous object?  Do you have two different models (an input and an output)?

Comment: No, just want all properties  but I need one in specific format. Like Javascript ... (three dots to include all properties)

Comment: Edited to include valid query

Comment: @Yuri you'll need some reflection here. Basically what you need is spread syntax from Javascript in C# right?

Comment: @MistyK I need just all properties from model with the same name but editing one property to delivery to the client. Like my second example... just need to know if there is any way to make less verbose.

Comment: https://automapper.org/ probably..

Comment: If you can add one more field in your ClientChartNotes without mapping to entity framework that would return Formatted Date (ChartNoteDate). That should solve the easiest way!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend selecting the Note itself and the additional field.

```
var notes = from n in myContext.Notes
        select new 
        {
            Note= n
            NewDate = n.date.ToString("MM/YYYY")
        }
```

So your notes will have all the Original Note and the additional properties you added in the result.

Comment: Must be exact properties names to return in the API

Comment: How can you set "ChartNoteDate" = ChartNoteDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
If ChartNoteDate is DateTime ?

Comment: Yes, because its turned in anonymous result. return Ok(note), and I dont care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query using lambda:

```
var fetchedNote = await myDbContext.Notes        // get the collection of all Notes
    .Where(note => note.ClientChartNoteId == Id) // take only those notes that ...
    .Select(note => new                  // from every remaining note, make one new object
    {                                    // with only the properties you plan to use
        Title = note.Title,              // some are original values
        ...
        Date = note.Data.ToString(...),  // some are calculated values
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```